# Setting up wifi on server version 18.04

Tags: networking

Today I tried installing Linux for the first time, and I can't get the Wi-Fi working. The Wi-Fi is built into the laptop, not a dongle.

- Firstly, how do I know that Ubuntu is even seeing the card? `ip link sho | grep w`  gives me a result. Will the result be the Wi-Fi card and not something else like the USB Ethernet dongle?

  - Based on the output, the card is down. Nothing seems to enable it. e.g. `sudo ifconfig <name> up` makes no difference
  - `sudo rfkil` shows this interface is unblocked, both soft and hard
  - trying the command:`wpa_passphrase MYSSID passphrase > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`  results in `permission denied`, even if I try using `sudo`

Can someone please suggest what I should try next - or possibly try in the correct sequence.

**Edited to add more information:**
[This is the walkthrough](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/connect-wifi-terminal-ubuntu-16-04/) that I found yesterday before coming here for help:

Martin Thornton gave me the correct syntax to get the wpa_passphrase working.
When I run `iwlist scan`, which is the next step in the walkthrough, it tells me the network is down.

The documentation linked below starts off with "Open the system menu" I don't think I have a menu?

Running `lspci` tells me the wireless card is an:

```
Intel Wireless 7260 (8086:08b1) rev 6b
```

`sudo lshw -C network` told me the wireless interface was disabled after running `sudo ip link set wlp6s0 up`, it seems the card is up. But `iwlist scan` still returns no scan results

Comment: I'd suggest installing a desktop version instead of a server one.

Comment: Regarding the "permission denied", because of the output redirection you'll need to use `sudo` this way: `wpa_passphrase MYSSID passphrase | sudo tee /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: wifi isn't usually found on servers, but did you get far with the documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html.en or https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en)  If so providing us with details of your wireless card would be useful via `sudo lshw -C network` (list-hardware of class=network found on the troubleshooer help page)

Comment: @fkraiem our linux guy in the office quit, and I need to work on our servers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Question re-opened [Have a look here first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), then [edit] your question and provide a link to the detailed configuration.  *Please help us help you!*  **0:-)**